# successfully display json in flutter, but not showing on android screen

Tags: flutter, api, dart, http, request

I've managed to display API data to flutter, but strangely it only appears in the debug console, but when hot reloaded, the data appears on the android screen.

**Code**

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    AuthProvider authProvider = Provider.of<AuthProvider>(context);
    UserModel? user = authProvider.user;
    JobsProvider? jobsProvider = Provider.of<JobsProvider>(context, listen: false);
    jobsProvider.getJobs(user?.token);

Widget newArrival() {
      return Container(
        margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
          top: 14,
        ),
        child: Column(
          children: jobsProvider.jobs
              .map(
                (jobs) => CardJob(),
              )
              .toList(),
        ),
      );
    }
```

**Before hot reload**
[image]

[image]

**After hot reload**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The problem has to do with the fact that the request's function is probably `async`.

Your code is not waiting for a response, instead it renders the page before the data is received.

Normally, you should add an await in front of the call, as: `await jobsProvider.getJobs(user?.token);` (if that's the function). But you cannot call an async function into the `build()` method. That's why you could use a [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html).

An example of the FutureBuilder that returns a String:

```
FutureBuilder<String>(
  future: myFunction("param"),
  builder:
      (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
      final theText = snapshot.data 
      Text(theText ?? ""),
    }
    return const CircularProgressIndicator() //While awaiting show the loading indicator
  },
),
```

Answer (score 0):

If the screen is as you wanted after hot reload it means that when the screen is drawn your data was not available. You can try to call **setState** after receiving the jobs json or if you do this task with the initialization of the screen make sure that you init the page **after** the data arrives.